# Is there any difference between initializing a variable (like formGroup) inside the class directly or inside the constructor of class?

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor, angular-forms

I just wondering what is the difference between initializing `formGroup` inside the class or inside the constructor.

1. Creating them when we are declaring them like this:

   ```
   form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({})
   ```
2. Declare its variable and then create them in `constructor` of `class`

   ```
   form: FormGroup;

   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
       this.form = this.formBuilder.group({})
   }
   ```

Are there any differences between these two approaches and what are the pros and cons of these two approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you showed is the same approach (inlined initialization will be moved to the constructor by the compiler).

Using the `FormBuilder` in itself is a short form though.

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  c1: new FormControl('')
});

==

form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  c1: ['']
});
```

Comment: is the second approach you have written equal to using the `new` keyword? shouldn't we avoid using `new` As far as possible؟

Comment: Yes, those are equal (hence the `==`). Using a FormBuilder is just a short form. Concerning `new`, I haven't heard that. It's the standard way of creating an instance of type. The reason you might not need it that often though is because those types need a constructor and usually you'd only use an interface for a type, not a class (in fact, a class needs to be instantiated using 'new' in typescript).